# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (VS Code Integrated Terminal)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET MVC. To run it, I use the following shell commands:

```
dotnet restore ProjectDirectory
```

and then

```
dotnet run --project ProjectDirectory
```

**If I run them in my command shell, all works fine.** But my code editor is VS Code, so I want to make it run these commands in its Integrated Terminal. I have configured its behavior in its files `launch.json` and `tasks.json`:

```json
// launch.json

{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "restore",
            "program": "C:/Windows/System32/dotnet.exe", // The directory separation char is / in this attribute (not \)
            "args": ["run", "--project", "${workspaceFolder}"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}

// tasks.json

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyWebApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyWebApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyWebApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        // Here is my preLaunchTask
        {
            "label": "restore",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "restore",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

After configuring I tried it out. I pressed `F5`. The Integrated Terminal opened, and it tried to run

```
dotnet restore ProjectDirectory
```

But then it showed the following error message:

> The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (CreateProcess failed)

## What I have tried

1. I opened VS Code documentation and made some research. I found only one [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch) about troubleshooting Integrated Terminal failures.
2. I tried all the advices from the troubleshooting page above. They didn't help me.
3. Surfed the Internet (including Stack Overflow). I found no useful pages (excluding the troubleshooting page descripted above).
4. Now I asked my own question.

Comment: MacOS? Windows? Debian?

Comment: @Pieterjan Windows

Comment: @SNBS Check your settings.json of VSCode. does it have the below line setup correctly "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"

Comment: @SNBS Have you tried opening VSCode with the "Run as Administrator" option? If not, try it and let me know what it does.

Comment: @ChinmayT Yes, it always runs as administrator. Maybe in two hours I will take time to check `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` and let you know.

Comment: @ChinmayT Didn't help. Nothing changed.

Comment: You need to change the below lines to the respective path of your project. I am able to restore and build using these values for my vanilla MVC project.  Change these values into launch.json file only. "preLaunchTask": "build",
                        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MvcWebApp/bin/Debug/net7.0/MvcWebApp.dll",
            "args": ["restore", "${workspaceFolder}"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MvcWebApp",

Comment: Let me know if you want full code or if this works for you, I will post an answer.

Comment: No, nothing changed. I'm starting to think it's because of a weird bug in VS Code, not because of the configuration.